# How to get sold products from third party app in magento database with complete payment and order

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise

How to get all purchased product by customer with third party app  in magento.I am using for this as follow

i am getting all products ids and their quantities from app then creating an order in magento for it but it  creates an order with pending state but i want to make it complete so this can add in sale tables with complete order So I can make it report easily of sold products.

Comment: Can you share the code you have already to create the order?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get an order with the code you already have, you should be able to create the invoice for this order with:

```
$invoice = $order->prepareInvoice();
$invoice->register()->capture();

Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($invoice)
    ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())->save();
```

This will create the invoice for all the available ordered items qty. To get the order invoiced you will alse need to create a shipment for all the available items. To create a new shipment for you order with:

```
    $shipment = $order->prepareShipment();
    if ($shipment) {
        $shipment->register();
        $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                ->addObject($shipment)
                ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                ->save();
    }
```